# Using Web.Caching on XP Running IIS 5.1 Not available?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, http-caching, system.web.caching

**Environment:** I am working on a site in ASP.Net 2.0 running on IIS6; I am developing locally on WinXP which runs IIS 5.1, using VS2005 and VB.

**Issue:** I am trying to create caching for some business layer objects (actually creating a caching layer) using System.web.caching.cache. This should be available under System.Web namespace but all that I seem to have access to are: AspNetHostingPermission, AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute and AspNetHostingPermissionLevel (I have a reference to System.Web in the project and imports in the class). There are quite a few other classes (e.g., HTTPRuntime) which also do not appear (this is per the "Using SQL Cache Dependencies" tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/caching-data/using-sql-cache-dependencies-vb).

I'm at the end of my rope and can't seem to find anything out there to explain this. Has anyone been in this situation and seen this before? Any help getting this solved is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so not sure why I didn't think of this before but I checked the references tab under the project properties. In the list for System.web, the additional namespaces were unchecked; checking System.Web.Caching and recompiling fixed the issue.

Sometimes you're just toooooo close to something to realize the easy answer.